# Tooltip Display Issue

Tags: silverlight, telerik, tooltip

I have added a tooltip into my code `ToolTipService.ToolTip="Submit Changes"` in Button control.
I also used a Radpane telerik control on my page.when i move mouse on button the tooltip is hiding behind Radpane control.

I want to display it on that telerik control. Please give me suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: The same issue is for progress bar also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this still giving you issues try changing the z-order of the ToolTip in relation to the button so that it displays on top of the control.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must first set property to enable focus behaiviars.

set IsHitTestVisible="True"